# Run Django as Windows Service

Tags: django, windows-services, nginx

I run Django on Windows Server 2k3 under Nginx using FastCGI.

Nginx is is running as Windows service and is easy to manage and autostart.
Nginx is running using [WINSW](http://kenai.com/projects/winsw) tool.

I want to make the same for Django app and need to find a way to do it.

Django should be started as separate FCGI application using this command:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8800
```

or

```
manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8800
```

(if .py is associated with python)

I'm looking for a way to start/stop FCGI Django as windows service, to be able to autostart it when windows loads, and to have an easy way to start/stop/restart Django FCGI application.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question to be more specific about what you're looking to accomplish.  Django is a web app framework that needs to be hosted by a webserver.  It's not a standalone application that can run by itself in such a way that would mean it needs to be autostarted.

Comment: Django could work as a separate FCGI application. I'm using Nginx webserver and runing Django as FCGI application behind Nginx is the standard way to run Django on Nginx AFAIK.

Actually i'm using IIS on Windows server. Firstly I tried to run Django on IIS - but it makes a lot of troubles and there was no way to do it on x64 Windows, so I decided to run Nginx as main webserver - as reverse proxy to IIS and as FCGI host for Django. Now looking for a nice way to work with Django FCGI app as service.

Comment: If you're still willing to run Django on Windows behind IIS, you may be interested by https://github.com/antoinemartin/django-windows-tools/

Comment: @T.Stone Can't we autostart the Django by issuing Django run server command in command prompt in a subprocess in Python using subprocess module https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may provide you with answers: [Creating a python win32 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263296/creating-a-python-win32-service)