# how to create a service in python in windows?

Tags: python, service, cron, window

I want to run a service in windows which will keep running in background and will run a cron with specific time.
how i can do that in windows using python?

Comment: See {Creating a python win32 service}(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263296/creating-a-python-win32-service).

Answer (score 3):

Use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). A tutorial was written (in 2005 mind you) [here](http://essiene.blogspot.com/2005/04/python-windows-services.html) about how one might do that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure win32 api is installed. Basically, you subclass the BasicNTService. The win32 package docs has some more information. I also have a working example in some code I wrote that does this.
[WindowsServer.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/QA/pycopia/remote/WindowsServer.py?r=380) that also mixes in Pyro for a Python remote control agent.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) and [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) could do the job.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/41992/how-to-configure-dropbox-as-a-service/42012#42012) for srvany usage (replace dropbox with your exe)