# How to run Python programs in the background?

Tags: python, background

I have a Python program that interfaces with the browser, and now I meed to make that as my background process, so that every time I click the button, the program should start running in the background.

Can anyone help me with an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a Unix-like system (e.g. Mac OSX, Linux), the command is `python myscript &`, which runs the command in the background. In general, in bash (as well as most other shells) if you append a `&` to your command it runs the command in the background.

Comment: Thanku for the reply and yes I am using Linux(Ubuntu) as my operating system .I will check the answer and get back to you if any doubts.

Comment: But in this case, if I close my terminal window the python process is killed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way your script is launched, backgrounding with & may not necessarily work since there's a non-login shell that might be what's launched - and it would terminate when your browser session terminates. But there's a whole existing thread dedicated to this issue: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python/92395#92395)

What you want to do is spawn either a separate process, or perhaps create a daemon that's started by your browser click.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're using Windows, this might help: [Creating a python win32 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263296/creating-a-python-win32-service)

Comment: you could also make a batch file with something like: start /b /min myprocess.py, but that's kind of ugly. there are probably other ways to do it too, but I try to steer clear of Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html or use http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/
or use:

```
* Creating your own HTTP requests using urllib2 standard python library
* Using a more advanced library that provides the capability to navigate through a websit simulating a browser such as  mechanize.
```

but the "trigger" which will fire the script on Linux, is what YOU have to develop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup python filename.py &
```